# Pass in array to JavaScript function using Mustache variable tag

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm using **Node.js Express** with **Hogan** templates, which I believe uses **Mustache** variable tags. I have a JavaScript array that I'm trying to pass into a JavaScript function that is part of my hogan template. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/z1ga8wgw/

If you check the JavaScript console and click on the error in there, you will notice that the template expanded into this, which gives an error:

```
function test([object Object],[object Object],[object Object]) {
    console.log('test');
}
```

The error I get in my actual application is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The error from JSFiddle gives is this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at DOMEval (jquery-git.js:82)
    at domManip (jquery-git.js:5782)
    at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery-git.js:5918)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):61)
    at mightThrow (jquery-git.js:3569)
    at process (jquery-git.js:3637)
```

I would like to be able to have one array as the argument, but as you can see, the amount of arguments can vary. I would settle for this type of behavior as well if there isn't an error because I believe you can use the **arguments** variable, but just one parameter would be best, if that's possible.

---

**Edit**

Here is the test code from the JSFiddle (which also has Mustache and JQuery as resources that I'm not listing here):

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="test">
    <script>
    function test({{data}}) {
        console.log('test');
    }
    </script>
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Got help with this template from: http://jsfiddle.net/evildonald/hqAnK/
$(document).ready(function () {
    var output = $("#output");    
    var template = $("#test").html();

    var data = { data : [
        {value : "1", text : "text 1"},
        {value : "2", text : "text 2"},
        {value : "3", text : "text 3"}
    ]};

    html = Mustache.render(template, data);
    output.append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mustach behaves correctly, what you are trying to do is not possible.

You are writting a function declaration, parameters must be variable names, not string representation of an array.

```
[
  {value : "1", text : "text 1"},
  {value : "2", text : "text 2"},
  {value : "3", text : "text 3"}
].toString()

// => [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

If you want to retrieve your array inside your template, you have to serialize it using `JSON.stringify`.

**Javascript**

```
var data = { 
  data : JSON.stringify(
    [
      {value : "1", text : "text 1"},
      {value : "2", text : "text 2"},
      {value : "3", text : "text 3"}
    ]
  )
};
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/html" id="test">
  <script>
    function test(data) {
      console.log('test', data);
    }

    // call your function with data as parameter
    test( {{{data}}} );
    //    ^^^    ^^^ Use {{{}}} syntax to not escape quotes into html entities
  </script>
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z1ga8wgw/1/

Comment: Interesting. I tried using JSON.stringify but didn't know to use three "{" and "}" when using the array as a param to the function.